# Redis SET Command in Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, redis

Probably a silly question but I can see from the redis docs that to SET a key to hold a string value I would use:

```
SET mykey "Hello"
```

but all the docs seem to focused on commands from the Command Line.

I am using Express.js (with node.js) and I want to be able to run the commands from my server.js file.

At the moment I have:

```
# db is a redis.createClient object set earlier in my code
db.set(mykey "Hello");
```

but this doesn't work - I get a syntax error warning.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a comma in your function call.  Redis uses spaces to separate arguments, but node.js uses commas.  So your code should look like:

```
db.set(mykey, "Hello")
```

Comment: thanks for this - actually I've since discovered that both the key and the val need quotes so `db.set("mykey", "Hello")` - thanks for the pointer though!

Comment: Whoops, I assumed that was a variable, sorry.  I'm glad you sorted it out.